# list of all selected items from django select2 plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

How can i pull out the list of all selected items in django select2 plugin?

So, I select 5 options in a select2 field and i want to use javascript and pass the list of selected options using an ajax call to the server.

Contrary to common select fields, it does not add the attribute "selected" on selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the selected from the item using .val() 
All the selected items are going to be comma separated.

```
$('#AlarmOptions').val()
```